# Making A Data Frame Using Entries That Meet A Variety Of Conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that has ~150 variables (a, b, c, d, ..., n) and ~180 cases. Each variable can have a response of 1, 2, or 3. I'm trying to create a new data frame that includes all of the cases where the response to 'a' was 1 AND/OR the response to 'b' was also 1.

I can do it for individual variables, but not for multiples. The code I've been using is:

```
df.new <- df.old[df.old$a == 1,]
```

Comment: Look into the `subset` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g. `df.new <- df.old[df.old$a == 1 | df.old$b == 1 , ]`.

Try `?"Logic"` for a full explanation of the logical operators in R. In this instance `|` is the **OR** operator. Beware operator precedence when chaining multiple logical operators together. Lookup up `"?Syntax"` to view the precedence of operators.